# How is a std::string parameter passed from a raw character array literal?

Tags: c++

First of all, I do not really know how I put title on this question..
So we have this code:

```
class Example5 {
    string* ptr;
  public:
    Example5 (const string& str) : ptr(new string(str)) {}
    ~Example5 () {delete ptr;}
    // access content:
    const string& content() const {return *ptr;}
};

int main () {
  Example5 foo ("Example");

  cout << "bar's content: " << foo.content() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

So the constructor of the `class Example5` is initializing the pointer `ptr` to be a pointer to `str`, right?

Is it an optimal way to have `const string& str` as the parameter instead of `string str`? I mean since `str` is used as something to be pointed to by `ptr`, why is the value of the argument not just get copied instead of making a reference to an unnamed entity/the string literal? Is this optimal?

Comment: Define _optimal_ please. `string* ptr;` `new string(str)` certainly isn't _optimal_.

Comment: No, by all standards, this is not optimal.

Comment: Warning: You have violated the Rule Of Three!

Comment: If the constructor is defined as   `Example5 (const string str) {....}`,  a copy of the argument takes place when the constructor is called, and another copy is done to fill the new string.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, why not? And is having a const reference optimal(good code, I am not sure what to say) when you need it as something to point to?

Comment: and should a const reference be used to a string literal? Hope this is not too confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the constructor of the `class Example5` is initializing the pointer `ptr` to be a pointer to `str`, right?

No! It creates a new `std::string` instance and copies what's passed in the parameter.

> why is the value of the argument not just get copied instead of making a reference to an unnamed entity/the string literal?

Good question, yes.

> Is this optimal?

No.

---

The usual way would be simply not to use a pointer at all:

```
class Example5 {
    string s;
  public:
    Example5 (const string& str) : s(str) {}
    // access content:
    const string& content() const {return s;}
};
```

---

To avoid taking a copy (if that's actually your concern) you could alternatively write

```
class Example5 {
    string s;
  public:
    Example5 (string str) : s(std::move(str)) {}
    // access content:
    const string& content() const {return s;}
};
```

Comment: I would say that the `const string& str` should usually be taken by value and `std::move`d into `s`: `Example5(string str) : s(std::move(str)) {}`. That way, if `str` would have been a reference to a temporary, we don't have to copy-construct (we can move-construct), and if `str` was not a reference to a temporary, we'd have to copy construct either way

Comment: @Justin That's a viable alternative yes. Let's not stress the OP to that extend overly for now.

Comment: Hmm thank you. But should you even use a const reference to a string literal? And then point to that const reference, like in the example?

Comment: It does not look stable

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't understand how it's overly doing it. Adding a `const&` or adding `std::move` are both trivial in term of difference in cognitive overhead. Maybe `std::move` is a lot to take for experienced programmer that did C++03 extensively, but for a beginner, both are some character added to enhance performance.

Comment: @Jake What do you mean? Keeping a `const` reference inside the class as a member? That might be dangerous to become dangling. That's stable as concrete, anything else isn't. What are you concerns regarding _stability_?

Comment: @JakeBlandon When taking a const reference and initialize a string with it, a copy is made. There is no dangling reference in both of πάντα ῥεῖ. Both example en up containing a fully constructed string. Remember that objects are not passed by reference by default, so when a class is containing a `std::string` directly, it will always be a valid string, unless there is undefined behavior somewhere else.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, but should you ever create a const reference to a value and then technically point to a string literal? Even though the pointer won't be dangling since it uses a const reference that will keep the literal string alive.

Comment: @Jake Note that your example simply copies the string as well. I don't get your confusions. There's no _string literal_ but an implicitely created `std::string` instance.

Comment: @JakeBlandon String literal don't have lifetime. They don't ever die. They are constant data embedded in the executable. In your code, you are creating an instance of the class `std::string` using the string literal. Both are different things. But since `std::string` can be constructed with a string literal, a `std::string` will be constructed using that literal, and the string constructor will copy bytes of the string literal into it's own buffer. Don't worry about literals lifetime.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, hmm okay then.. But then you are saying that the literal is technically still being copied even though the parameter is a reference which is used to avoid copying values, right?

Comment: @Jake You're completely off what's going on in your examle. 1. A `std::string` instance is implicitely created using the character array literal. 2. It's passed as a const rference to the constructor 3. `new` is called to crate another `std::string` instance assigned to `ptr` 4. The value is copied from the const reference passed as parameter. I'm out of words to explain that more now.